# Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a simple app to help a diabetic calculate some different things they would need to help regulate their blood sugar.  At the bottom of the page I want to state a few different things as a quick overview.  So when I try and pull Carbs down to my list, it doesnt work.  What do i do? Code is shown below

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="Austin" content="HTML Code and Java Script">
  <title>Title</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function doseToEat() {
      var carbs = parseFloat(document.getElementById("carbs").value);
      var insulin = parseFloat(document.getElementById("insulinUnitPer10Carbs").value);
      var dose = carbs / (insulin * 10)
      document.getElementById("dose").innerHTML = dose;
      documnet.getElementById("carbsOutput").innerHTML = carbs;
    }

    function correction() {
      var currentBS = parseFloat(document.getElementById("currentBS").value);
      var correction = (currentBS - 100) / 30
      document.getElementById("correction").innerHTML = correction;
      document.getElementById("currentBSOutput").innerHTML = currentBS;
    }
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <h3>This Is to help calculate and track your blood sugar.</h3>
  <input type="number" id="currentBS">Please Enter your current Blood Sugar.
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="correction()">Calculate Correction</button>
  <br>
  <label>This is your correction.</label>
  <div id="correction"></div>
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="carbs">How many Carbs will you be eating?
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="insulinUnitPer10Carbs">How many Units of Insulin do you need per 10 carbs?
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="doseToEat()">Calculate</button>
  <br>
  <label>This Is How much Insulin you should dose</label>
  <div id="dose"></div>

  <output type="number" id="time">Time:</output>
  <br>
  <output type="number" id="Date">Date:</output>
  <br>Current Blood Sugar:
  <output type="number" id="currentBSOutput"></output>
  <br>Carbs:
  <output type="number" id="carbsOutput"></output>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've misspelled document.

Comment: `documnet` ==> `document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have miss spelled `document`, need to change this

```
documnet.getElementById("carbsOutput").innerHTML = carbs;
^------^
```

to

```
document.getElementById("carbsOutput").innerHTML = carbs;
```

Comment: This should really be a comment.